# Stove Vent Hood Not Pulling Air

Tags: vent, stove, hood

My stove vent is not pulling enough air but the exhaust on the outside of my house is flowing really good. The metal grease filters have been replaced (in fact with the grease filters removed it still doesnt pull good air). The fans both spin just fine and like I said the exhaust on the outside of the house is blowing plenty of air. Need help please?

Comment: Is it possible there is a leak or opening in the vent duct?

Comment: Has there been a change? How did you determine that it's not pulling enough air? That's very subjective and I would like to understand what it means to you

Comment: I checked the vent duct and its no hole or leakage.

Comment: No change, hasnt been touched. The determination that its not pulling enough air is when I cook something and if it happens to smoke/burn my house gets filled with smoke to the point of the smoke detectors. Also I do the tissue test and it really is week. I do light a match, blow it out and watch the smoke gently go into the fan

Comment: am I just expecting it to pull too much and maybe dont cook things that smoke?lol

Comment: Open a window or door to provide make up air. A tightly sealed home may not allow the exhaust fan to function right.

Comment: Expectations do need to be considered. Note that the hood over the stove is much bigger than the vent pipe. Even if working at 100% the speed of the air flow at the hood is going to be much less, increasing until it enters the duct pipe. You can test the inflow of the ducting pipe at the hood end to see if it about the same as what you noted for the outflow. If it's significantly different than it's a duct leak as noted by jwh20

Comment: Is this a new home to you? I ask because this sounds like the fans are operating normally and ether you burn more than the previous owners or have larger pans , I know when we use our huge skillet smoke gets outside the hood if we don’t use the center burners or the ones next to the griddle and we have 3 fans and a 6” duct with a make up air vent under the stove. So if smoke is getting outside the hood with good air flow you need smaller pans , or stop burning things, and my wife did not think it was funny when I told her that but she already has a commercial hood.